# Is possible that an entire function satisfies this condition?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ an entire function whose only zeros are all the negative integers. Is possible that $f$ satisfies $|f(z)|\leq C_1 e^{C_2 |z|^p},$ for some real constants $C_1, C_2,$ and $p<1$?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply the given function with the Gamma Function, and then study the growth rate.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I don't see why it helps. Would be happy for further explanation.